# Make a calculation in postgresql from two tables

Tags: postgresql

I want to make a calculation with values from two different tables. 
It is about calculating the avg_sellingprice from dataset 1 / stddev_sellingprice from dataset 2.

If I use (avg_sellingprice FROM dataset1 / stddev_sellingprice FROM dataset2)it won't work.

[image: dataset1]

[image: dataset2]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overlfow. Your question will be easier to understand and more attractive if you provide your sample data as *tabular text*. You would also need to show the result that you expect for this sample data, so what you want is unambiguous.

Comment: In addition to what GMB wrote: see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use JOIN command to gather values which you want to make calculation between them. Then, you can easily make calculations.